# Get rid of empty lines in a .txt with javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems

Hello I have a questions regarding fs and the removing of a specific string.
I have multiple words in a a .txt one word in each line

e.g:

Bird
Eagle
Pig
Horse

Now i want to remove the "Pig" from the text file.

```
function readWriteSync() {
            var data = fs.readFileSync("links.txt", 'utf-8');
            var newValue = data.replace(links[i], '');
          
            fs.writeFileSync("links.txt", newValue, 'utf-8');
          }
        readWriteSync()

    }
```

I am able to remove the specific line, however the file still contains empty lines, is there any way to fix the issue and get rid of the blank lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace all consecutive new lines into a single new line after you done replacing:

```js
newValue = newValue.replace(/\n{2,}/g, '\n');
```

Which looks like this:

```js
function readWriteSync() {
  var data = fs.readFileSync("links.txt", 'utf-8');
  var newValue = data.replace(links[i], '');
  newValue = newValue.replace(/\n{2,}/g, '\n');
          
  fs.writeFileSync("links.txt", newValue, 'utf-8');
}
```

You may see the replacement result [here](https://regex101.com/r/6NizC2/1/)

Comment: is there a way to split the single new line again so Bird, Eagle and Horse are seperated by lines again ?

Comment: @MaxiiPaguera You could ask a new question about this and provide some details how you want it to be done.